# C++ Native Windows Phone 8 - Render text to texture

Tags: c++, windows-phone-8, fonts, native, text-rendering

I was wondering what's the easiest way of rendering character glyphs to a texture, using c++ native code, on a windows phone 8 device. Function calls/API reference appreciated.

For background, this is part of a "fallback font" system, where it's meant to be used if the glyph requested to the custom fonts we pack in the app does not exist. So it needs to have at least *some* metrics data available (w/h and bearings being the very basics).

The only leads I have so far are the DirectWrite/Direct2D apis, but they only work for 8.1 (not 8.0) so I thought I'd ask in case someone with more experience has a better suggestion.

Thanks,
Jaime